# What does “resp.” mean?

Tags: definition

[In the libxml2 documentation for the function xmlNodeSetContent](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeSetContent), it says:

> Replace the content of a node. NOTE: @content is supposed to be a piece of XML CDATA, so it allows entity references, but XML special chars need to be escaped first by using xmlEncodeEntitiesReentrant() resp. xmlEncodeSpecialChars().

I don’t understand “resp.” here. I have also seen similar phrasing in some SO questions. My Google-fu was weak and unable to help, so I ask:

What does “resp.” stand for here, and what does it mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English.

Comment: This question about the English language has nothing to do with this forum. You should ask it on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Considering that I’m an over-40 native English speaker and that I’ve only encountered this usage here and in the libxml2 docs, I believed the question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

resp. is the short way of saying "respectively". So you are able to use both methods.